# fatal error: studio.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to learn how to program in C.
I'm simultaneously learning C, C++, & Java.  I have also coded in html and javascript successfully making rich websites.
I'm following video lessons on skillshare.  Through VirtualBox I've set up a ubuntu installation, created lesson001.c, and attempted to compile it by entering "gcc lesson001.c"

The program:

```
#include <studio.h>
int main(){
printf("hello, world!\n");
return 0;
}
```

The error:

lesson001.c:1:10 fatal error: studio.h: no such file or directory.

The instructor is walking through the coding lesson on a pre-configured linux system, so he does have the same errors.  It is frustrating that a comprehensive paid lesson set does not include critical setup parameters.

additional info: "gcc -v" returns about 20 lines of information on gcc 9.3.0, so I believe it is installed correctly.

Thank you

Comment: Programming requires _really strict_ attention to detail. `#include <stdio.h>`. There is no studio. (It is probably just a typo by the professor. (He/She _should_ be compiling and vetting everything presented to you before doing so, though.)

Comment: It will help you significantly if you get yourself a https://www.cppreference.com/. It can be a pretty dense read at times, but it does have a lot of very helpful examples. :O)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `#include <studio.h>` declaration to `#include <stdio.h>`. A header file named `studio.h` does not exist in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

`stdio` stands for "standard input/output," and has nothing to do with "studio"!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `stdio` instead of `studio`.
`stdio` stands for Standard Input Output

Correctly formatted code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```